# Is port 443 working for gRPC running behind nginx?

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose, grpc

I setup a test environment to place docker, nginx before grpc server. And below are my configurations

docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: gunicorn --timeout 100 --workers 2 --threads 4 django_root.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/public/django_root/static
        expose: 
            - 8000
        env_file: 
            - ./.env.dev
    grpc:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py grpcrunserver 0.0.0.0:50051
        env_file: 
            - ./.env.dev
    nginx:
        build:
          context: ./nginx
          dockerfile: Dockerfile-secure
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/public/django_root/static
        ports:
            - 1337:80
            - 443:50052
        depends_on: 
            - web
            - grpc
volumes: 
    static_volume:
```

Dockerfile-secure

```
FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx-secure.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

nginx-secure.conf

```
upstream django_root {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django_root;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /public/django_root/static/;
    }

}

log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                           '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                           '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

server {
    listen 50052 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/server.key;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/a.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/e.log;

    location / {
        grpc_pass grpc://grpc:50051;
    }
}
```

The problem I hit is port 443 not working as I setup above in docker-compose file, but if I replace it with 8443, then my client can talk with grpc server. The error I can see from my client for port 443 use
case is below

```
E0211 15:08:05.178000000 22572 src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:1439] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
```

I use self-signed certificate for this test environment on localhost, could this be the problem?
I do not see 443 been disallowed for this case in neither nginx site or docker site. Need help on this, and in case 443 not allowed for this case, please refer me to the document.

Comment: I never see an example connecting grpc client with server behind nginx in a docker use port 443. So strange 

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's certificate itself. Replacing self-signed certificate with let'sencrypt one and deploy to aws makes port 443 working.